# Suppose $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n x^n= \frac{x^3}{(x^4-1)^2}$. What could be an expression of $b_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, generating-functions, geometric-series

A practice problem reads:

Suppose $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n x^n = \frac{x^3}{(x^4-1)^2}.$$

What could be an expression of $b_n$?

Some of the possible answers read $ 2^{3n}nx^{3n-1}, nx^{3n-1}, nx^{4n-1}$

There are a few other answers. I was just not sure how to start this problem?

Comment: Have you heard of Taylor series?  That could be one place to start.

Comment: the expression depends on the value of $x$ because the radius of convergence of a geometric series is $1$.

Comment: Hint $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ny^{n} =\frac{y}{(1-y)^2}$ ... $y \rightarrow x^{\color{red}{?}}$ ...

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**

$$\int \frac{x^3}{(x^4-1)^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{4(1-x^4)}+C$$

Expand $\frac{1}{1-z}$ in a geometric series and set $z=x^4$?

Comment: Does that mean I can say $$\int \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n x^n = \frac{1}{4(1-x^4)} + C$$ could be written as a power function $$ \sum z^n,  $$  where z = x^2? $$

Comment: Note quite.  Note $z=x^4$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark

Answer (score 2):

Another variation is based  upon the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
\begin{align*}
(1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{\alpha}{n}x^n\qquad\qquad |x|<1
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{x^3}{(x^4-1)^2}&=x^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-2}{n}(-x^4)^n\tag{1}\\
> &=x^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+1}{1}x^{4n}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (n+1)x^{4n+3}\tag{2}\\
> &=x^3 + 2 x^7 + 3 x^{11} + 4 x^{15} + 5 x^{19} + 6 x^{23}+\cdots
> \end{align*}

In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.

> We conclude according to (2) the representation
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (n+1)x^{4n+3}
> \end{align*}
>   implies for $n\geq 0$
>   \begin{align*}
> b_{4n+k}=
> \begin{cases}
> n+1&\qquad k=3\\
> 0&\qquad k\neq 3
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}